# Non-newtonian fluid

Tags: modeling, physics, cloth-simulation

I am working on a project where it is necessary to simulate a non-Newtonian fluid.
The problem lies in the object's "non-responsiveness" to another object.

In my case, it is a car and a lying policeman.
The structure of the lying policeman consists of 3 meshes.

- On the top is Cloth (to make a pillow look)
- Fluid Domain
- and Flow.

I don't know how to make the car react to the object, the keys and the collision don't work. Do I need go Rigid wheels? I really don't know. If I made it too complicated, I will be grateful for an explanation of how it can be done. And yes, i need that the car does not "pass" through a lying policeman, but rather moves over the landscape

[image: pic1]
[Fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid)

Comment: This sounds more like a softbody than a fluid to me.

Comment: My fluid is doesnt work rn. This "softbody" its cloth modifier. How i can a picture without post editing

Comment: @BoJo The same for me (as BlenderMaster15) ... what is the purpose of fluid in your workflow? Is you need just something similar to "pillow" physics use under Physics Properties > Softbody or  Cloth modifier with Internal Spings. If you don't plan to let pillow explode and splash blood everywhere :) BTW why "non-newtonian" fluid?

Comment: @vklidu. this is a physics project. The bottom line is that I can't do a car simulation. I tried all the ways, and through SoftBody/Collission. In general, the essence of the project is that the car could drive over a lying policeman as if on a landscape (that is, a simulation of movement through loc/roc)

Comment: @vklidu pt2. , and the lying policeman would sag under it like a pillow, but my car would pass by. Googling the article, I came across a liquid and tried to simulate the liquid so that the project was interactive, but now I would at least make the car move along the Z line, which I can't do (newbie in animation)

Comment: For a newbie quite a big bite :) A car rig is one big capture ... I don't know how complex your animation is (or what can be faked for just an illusion seen by camera), but try find out simplest way that match your final needs than sophisticated mechanism (or try to find free model of rigged car if you thing you would be able to control).

Answer (score 4):

*Just a quick tip until someone help you with something more sophisticated.*

---

### Cloth modifier

- for "pillow" set under *Physics Properties > Cloth* enable **Internal Springs**
- for *Plane* set *Collision* with **Friction** 30
- for "wheel" set keyframed animation (loc/rot) ... no physics here

[image]

[image]

Comment: ill try it. Thank u for this one

Comment: IMHO this makes more sense than a fluid sim to simulate "a car and a lying policeman".

Comment: it doesnt working. how can i drop the video?

Comment: It would be better share your blend file ... try to delete all parts that doesn't participate on your issue and share via https://blend-exchange.com